# querying for records with date between two dates in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am having a problem where I am trying to find records with a particular username and where the start date is between a start and end date. I have searched around and below is the seemingly agreed upon answer for how to do this. Unfortunately when I use it I still get the same error:

Due to limitations of the `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject`, you can't add a second 'start' expression specified

The query I am attempting to use is:

```
Query query = new Query(
                        Criteria.where("username").is(username)
                            .andOperator(
                                Criteria.where("start").lt(DateUtils.ceiling(date)),
                                Criteria.where("start").gte(DateUtils.floor(date)) 
                             )
                        );
```

I am using spring-data-mongoldb 1.8.4.RELEASE

Comment: That should work. Are you sure that error is from same the code sample that you have provided? The error given would normally happen when you have multiple andOperators.

Comment: I just confirmed it: org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'start' expression specified as 'start

I cleaned the project out to ensure it wasn't an old compile causing problems and thats the error. Not sure how to post a stacktrace on here for you?

Answer (score 0):

So this does in fact work properly. I just spent the last few hours ripping my code apart and rewriting it... Comparing with version in git shows no differences except now it works.

Just wanted to post this answer for anyone who comes looking. I really have no explanation as I was cleaning the project between runs, perhaps some copy of the old class was being held by the app server.